# Azure DevOps pipeline - Docker failed to push image to Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have created a "Docker - Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry" pipeline. I have selected the Azure subscription and the docker registry. After that, a docker registry service connection is made during the pipeline creation. Next, I modified the `azure-pipelines.yml` file to use a **self-hosted agent pool** and disabled the trigger.

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '***'
  imageRepository: 'devops'
  containerRegistry: '***.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool: my-personal-computer
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: $(tag)
```

However, running the pipeline resulted in an error. The `Build and push an image to container registry` task failed after pushing the docker image to Azure Container Registry. Here is the log message:

```
The push refers to repository [***/devops]
63b2598121d3: Preparing
8851d7ecbda2: Preparing
e76d0c14c9a4: Preparing
e016983c630a: Preparing
5f859dff6480: Preparing
bbf9d20826f5: Preparing
d8fab46d7ad4: Preparing
2e4e72005dce: Preparing
24839d45ca45: Preparing
bbf9d20826f5: Waiting
d8fab46d7ad4: Waiting
2e4e72005dce: Waiting
24839d45ca45: Waiting
denied: retrieving permissions failed
##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

It said that retrieving the permission failed. So I executed both the **Docker Desktop** and the `<my-selfhosted-agent-path>\run.cmd` as administrator. Unfortunately, it did not solve the issue. Therefore I looked inside the `<my-selfhosted-agent-path\_diag` folder and checked out a Worker log:

```
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Total accessible running process: 334.
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Inspecting process environment variables. PID: 21688 (SearchProtocolHost)
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z WARN BuildJobExtension] Ignore exception during read process environment variables: Access is denied.
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Inspecting process environment variables. PID: 4384 (SearchFilterHost)
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z WARN BuildJobExtension] Ignore exception during read process environment variables: Access is denied.
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Inspecting process environment variables. PID: 20736 (docker)
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Inspecting process environment variables. PID: 22712 (conhost)
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Inspecting process environment variables. PID: 1664 (com.docker.cli)
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z INFO BuildJobExtension] Inspecting process environment variables. PID: 4476 (docker-scout)
[2023-07-11 09:01:16Z INFO JobRunner] Job result after all job steps finish: Failed
```

It looks like there are some access problems during the job. I do not know why docker failed to push the image when yesterday everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to successfully run the pipeline by recreating a completely new pipeline. I deleted the automatically created pipeline under the **Pipelines** page, the `azure-pipeline.yml` file from the repository, and the service connection under the **Project Settings** > **Pipelines** > **Service Connections** setting.

Next, I generated the "Docker - Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry" Azure pipeline. I selected the subscription and the Azure Container Registry (ACR). I modified the `azure-pipeline.yml` file to use my self-hosted agent and disabled the trigger.

```
trigger: none

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: '***'
  imageRepository: 'devops'
  containerRegistry: '***.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool: my-personal-computer
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: $(tag)
```

I tried to reproduce the problem after the successful runs:

- Running the `run.cmd` without admin rights
- Running the **Docker Desktop** without admin rights
- Switching to the company network instead of my mobile hotspot

But nothing... I was unable to reproduce the problem. I have no idea how the problem was fixed. It seems that "pressing the reset button" solves the issue. :)